# Kies stuck on "connecting" on Mac+Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-kies, macos

I have the latest version of Kies, OS X, and a Samsung Galaxy s2 with CM10 on it.
It is set to MTP with USB debugging off (if it's on USB storage rather than MTP, Kies crashes).
I tried playing with many parameters but none of them seem to work - when I plug in my Galaxy, Kies shows "connecting" and nothing happens.. (the program itself is not stuck).

Someone suggested launching phone util (7284) and changing the PDA/modem stuff, but it doesn't launch on my phone, I guess it's because of my CM10.

I also tried rebooting the phone/Mac several times.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Kies with custom ROMs (like CM), only with Samsung ROMs.